# JavascriptInterface (WEBVIEW) does not work with params

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I'm using Javascript to call a Java class and execute some code.

It works perfecly when using it without any parameters but if I'm using them, javascript doesn't find the Java code and the error "Uncaught Error: Method not found" shows up in the log. What could the problem be? Notice: This is not the whole code but you may spot the problem. Thank you!

Java

```
class CalculateObject {

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String calculateSum(String ab) {



        Toast.makeText(WEB.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return "2";
    }
```

Javascript

```
window.ob.calculateSum("92321");
```

Comment: Someone that can help? Tried everything...

Comment: Are you sure that the Javascript interface name is "ob"?